# Computed property for element in array

Tags: arrays, ember.js, computed-properties

I'm trying to make a computed that should return true if a given string is present in an array.

My model has a property on it that is an array of `user_id`'s that look something like this

```
"item_bid_history": [
  562,
  697,
  13193
]
```

I can get the currently logged in user's id which would be `13193`

Currently I have something like this

```
bidding: Ember.computed('item.item_bid_history','userService.user_id',function(){
    return Ember.$.inArray(this.get('userService.user_id'),this.get('item.item_bid_history')) > -1;
})
```

Maybe I'm doing that wrong but even if I attempt to `console.log` the value of `inArray` I always get `-1` even though the `user_id` is in some of the item's `item_bid_history` arrays

Is there maybe a macro that will do this for me or am I just not creating the computed properly?

Comment: Make sure you use `[]` for arrays, otherwise the computed property won't trigger again when adding/removing values in the array: `Ember.computed('item.item_bid_history.[]', ...`

Comment: Why are you using jQuery?

Comment: Well Ember loads in it so I figured just use it, should I not?

Comment: Ember's Enumerable class (and by inheritance, arrays) has some useful methods which are preferable to use for non-DOM interactions in Ember. In your case you'll be interested in `contains` so you can just say `return this.get('item.item_bid_history').contains(this.get('userService.user_id'));` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure, the the `this.get('userService.user_id')` is 13193 (Number) and not "13193" (String). The $.inArray() wont find it, if it was typeof String.

```
$.inArray(123, [123, 1234])
//0

$.inArray("123", [123, 1234])
//-1
```

Comment: Duh that was it, didn't even think about that, wish I could tell it to not use `===` and just use `==`

Comment: Use of `==` is generally discouraged unless you have a very good reason to use it. The difference between "13193" and 13193 can lead to some unexpected and hard to find bugs down the line!